# Selecting the last child in css

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I have a markup that can take the following forms

```
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h3></h3>
<bl>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</bl>
<p></p>
```

or

```
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h3></h3>
<bl>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</bl>
```

I would like to create a common selector that could select the last p tag or the last li in the last bl tag.
P.S. I would like to do it with plain CSS

Comment: `p:last-child{ }` this for last `p` tag

Comment: @KarthikNayak98 Will that select li tag as well?

Comment: @rraj Is this for some competition related to code wars or to satisfy someone's ego? :)

Comment: Read more about `:last-child` selector

Comment: I kind of figured that last-child is the way to go... but the div are dynamically generated so cant add classes or use two different style rules

Comment: bl:last-child { p: last-child: {} } should solve

Comment: This needs some clarification, on what you actually want to select, and based on what _exactly_. The last `li` in your 2nd example is not the last child of whatever container element this whole markup is in, it is only the last child of its own parent, `bl` (what is that supposed to be, btw:? Not an actual HTML element.) CSS can not dynamically determine whether you actually meant the last child, or the last child of the last child.

Comment: @Yadab that nesting of rules would not be CSS though, and only work in a preprocessor like SASS or LESS.

Comment: @CBroe What about `bl:last-child p:last-child {}` Wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Yadab the space between those two selector parts is the “descendant combinator”. But there is no `p` that is a descendant of `bl` here.

Comment: If both `li` and `p` are present it will apply styles for both. @CBroe. According to him, it should be either `p` or `li`,

Comment: @CBroe In that case he can use `bl:last-child li:last-child {}` where li is a descendant of bl. This one is for his second question. for the last p `p:last-child {}` is good. Isn't it?

Comment: `p:last-child, bl:last-child li:last-child` would select the last `p` with the first example code, and the last `li` in the last `bl` in the second. So both, combined with a comma, to create one rule that will work for both codes.

Answer (score -1):

Just a `.class` or `#id` for the specific tag. Or just `li:last-child`.

Comment: The markup is dynamically generated I cant add a class to any div

Comment: you can add `.class` using javascript @rraj

Comment: @KarthikNayak98 I would use the js based approach as my last resort, still wondering if its possible to create a common CSS selector